# How to click item on a new website HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to code an auto clicker that can open a new tab on the click of an HTML button and start clicking. When clicked, JS should open a new tab and begin clicking. However, it does not seem to work. I have figured out that the JS will not run on a new tab, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Code sample below:

```
function updateButton() {
  window.open("https://clickthatbutton.com", '_blank');
  document.getElementById("submit").click();
}
```

Comment: are you ok to use jQuery? or use only pure javascript?

Comment: Are you trying to automate clicking on a different domain? This seems like something that would be blocked by browsers for security reasons (You could use a script loading browser extension, but a webpage will not have permission to do that)

Comment: @TomaszBucko I don't know jQuery, but I would be open to learning it if it would solve my problem

Comment: @DBS Yes, it is a different domain. My website is a different domain than the site I want to click on.

Comment: That isn't possible unless you own the other domain as well. Think about the security risks if that was allowed: User goes to site A, clicks a button, it takes them to site B and automatically clicks a button. Unfortunately, site B is a bank website and the button it clicked was to send site A money. (This is an over simplified example, but hopefully it gives you a rough idea)

Comment: This seems shady at best and it will only work if you can run Javascript on the `clickthatbutton.com` page.

Comment: @DBS That does make sense, seems like a terrible security risk. Should I resort to making a chrome extension instead that does the same?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to achieve, what is the goal of this code?

Comment: @DBS I'm trying to make a website that can open a new tab to click and checkout of websites quickly before items go out of stock. I guess I could make it a chrome extension but doing so would mean I wouldn't be able to use my Flask Oauth system. Would prefer a website because it looks better.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) says `window.open` returns object representing created window. So you can store it in variable and access its document:

```js
function updateButton() {
  const w = window.open("https://clickthatbutton.com", '_blank');
  w.document.getElementById("submit").click();
}
```